# How to run application in notification area after closing the application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a created a demo application, and would like to run always like antivirus, micromax datacard software, or any other notification software..

My Main objective is:
When I close an application then my application may close, but it should run and display in notification area icon like gtalk, skypee, etc. and when it will click then the application window will open and display it in task bar.

how to do it please describe it with code and examples

Comment: Is this a WinForms application? WPF? Silverlight? Something else?

Comment: @Jeremy What do services have to do with this question?

Comment: When I close an application then my application may close, but it should run and display in notification area icon like gtalk, skypee, etc

Comment: Windows Services don't show any UI whatsoever, so they won't show up in the notification area, either @Jeremy.

Comment: hmmm, you're right so is another exe the only way? oh ok, just read your profile you dont do chat.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that you aware of notify icon and context menu strip in WinForms.
Add ContextMenustrip  choose Edit items and add `show` and `Exit` menu item tool strips. Add corresponding click events.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //Form Closing Event
            e.Cancel = true;
            Hide();
        }

        private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Exit in notify icon Context menu tool strip
           Environment.Exit(-1);
        }

        private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Show in notify icon context menu tool strip
            Show();
        }
    }
}
```